# Programmatically insert list elements in R cbind()

Tags: r, cbind

I have a list of dates 2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011 created by the command

```
  dates <-sort(seq(2006,2011,1))
```

I use this same list of dates in several places, is there a way to access them, perhaps with

```
 sprinf %s
```

instead of typing them?  Here are two examples where I use this list.

```
BS_INC <-cbind(mean(BS_2006$INCSAL), mean(BS_2007$INCSAL), mean(BS_2008$INCSAL),
                    mean(BS_2009$INCSAL), mean(BS_2010$INCSAL), mean(BS_2011$INCSAL))

bsRusInc <- as.vector(cbind(mean(Russ_BS_2006$INCSAL), mean(Russ_BS_2007$INCSAL), mean(Russ_BS_2008$INCSAL),
                             mean(Russ_BS_2009$INCSAL), mean(Russ_BS_2010$INCSAL), mean(Russ_BS_2011$INCSAL)))
```

Comment: Put your data.frames in a named list, then `sapply(2006:2011, function(x){df_list[[grep(x, names(df_list))]]$INCSAL})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paste0, eval, parse and sapply:

```
dates <-sort(seq(2006,2011,1))
var_list <- paste0("BS_",dates,"$INCSAL")
BS_INC <- sapply(var_list, function(x) mean(eval(parse(text = x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you need but you can save some space by defining a function:

```
BS_INC <-cbind(mean(BS_2006$INCSAL), mean(BS_2007$INCSAL), mean(BS_2008$INCSAL),
                    mean(BS_2009$INCSAL), mean(BS_2010$INCSAL), mean(BS_2011$INCSAL))
# instead of this, you can...
getit <- function(x) mean(x$INCSAL)
sapply(list(BS_2006, BS_2007, BS_2008, BS_2009, BS_2010, BS_2011), getit)

# and further:
sapply(lapply(paste0("BS_", 2006:2011), get), getit)
```

Although it might perhaps be better to store your data in a list rather than in n+1 separate data frames.

Comment: is get getit in the #and further:?